# Maintain the area of a polygon when offsetting one side

Tags: geometry, polygons

I have an irregular polygon with the a specific area (area_red). How can I get the (parallel) offset value (y) of n selected sides in order to maintain the same area (area _red = area_green) when (parallel) offsetting one side by x?

[image]

Comment: Any additional info on the red? All angels known? Measures of sides? Any right angle? Any parallel sides?

Comment: U have three trapezoid.. you could calculate based on the angels the new sides as related to the old and get a relation between y and x to maintain areas of the two y trapezoid to equal the x one.